# LibreOffice Impress won't export pdf images properly

Tags: libreoffice-impress

I am creating a presentation in LibreOffice that uses some slides created in a different software (LaTeX) which have been exported to PDF (all fonts are embedded). I have the slides from the other presentation saved as *individual* pdf images with the same aspect ratio and page size as my presentation.

I can insert the slides by dragging-and-dropping but this makes the appearance pixelated and small text is totally unreadable. This problem is resolved when exporting the presentation to pdf, and vector graphics display properly. However, only about half the inserted images will appear when exporting to PDF, and I cannot see anything distinguishing the "valid" images from the "invalid" ones.

If I instead select "print to pdf", then all images display as expected, but in this case they are still unreadably pixelated. Is this a bug or can I change some setting to fix this?